# Menu aparece no emulador, mas não aparece no celular

Tags: android, html5

Criei um app no Eclipse utilizando o AppFramework da Intel, com HTML5 e tudo mais.No Browser ele roda normal, no emulador do android roda normal; porém, quando exporto o APK, ele não mostra o menu, que, no caso, é uma div footer, com alguns ícones.

No APK (rodando direto no celular), aparece somente a primeira página do app e nada mais. 
Como resolver isso?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>  </title>
<!--
    This template can be used for simple tab view application that has tabs at the bottom to switch views, for applications like Phone app, Facebook App or Instagram app.
--> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />
<style type="text/css">

.list-image {float: left;width: auto;height:50px}
.list-text {margin-left: auto;min-height:50px}   


</style>

</head>
<body> 
<div id="afui">

    <div id="content" style=""> 

    <!--Tab View Pages-->
        <div class="panel" title="Home" id="page1" data-tab="tab1" selected="true">
            <header>
                <h1><b>Quem somos</b></h1>
            </header>

            <p>A   &   é uma ótima oportunidade para pessoas que querem ganhar um dinheiro a mais. 
                A empresa de venda social permite às mulheres ter seu próprio negócio de moda ao tornar-se uma estilista, a qual é responsável 
                pelas vendas das joias da marca. Os produtos são exclusivos, com características finas e delicadas, e elaborados por profissionais 
                com mais de 10 anos de mercado, que fazem com total zelo e dedicação a produção e finalização dos itens. 
                O papel da estilista é auxiliar a potencial compradora a escolher as joias da marca que mais realçarão sua beleza.<br /> 
                A   &   disponibiliza ferramentas online para ajudar a estilista a conquistar clientes fiéis e oferece 50% 
                de desconto para adquirir os primeiros itens. <br />
                Sem dúvidas, ser uma parceira de negócios da   &   traz 
                muitas vantagens para a mulher moderna!</p>
        </div>



        <!-- Tendências -->


        <div class="panel" title="Favorites" id="page2" data-tab="tab2">
            <header>
                <h1>Tendências</h1>
            </header>
            <p>Esteja sempre linda, acompanhe nossas dicas e fique por dentro das tendências.</p> <br />

           <ul class="list">

                <li>
                    <img class="list-image" src="imagens/brincos2.jpg" /> &nbsp;
                    <a href="#detailview">Agarradinho as orelhas</a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <img class="list-image" src="imagens/caselux.jpg" /> &nbsp;
                    <a href="#detailview2">Arrumando as malas</a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <img class="list-image" src="imagens/colar.jpg" /> &nbsp;
                    <a href="#colar">1001 colares</a>

                </li>

            </ul>



        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Dicas" id="page3" data-tab="tab3">
            <header>
                <h1>Dicas de Moda</h1>
            </header>
            <p>Acompanhe nossas dicas e esteja sempre fashion</p>
            <ul class="list">

                <li><a href="#detailview">Anéis</a></li>
                <li><a href="#detailview2">Brincos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#detailview">Colares</a></li>
                <li><a href="#detailview">Pedras</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
                <div class="panel" title="Brincos" id="detailview" data-footer="none">
                                    <img src="imagens/brincos.jpg" alt=" " style="max-width: 100%; border-image:round"/>
            <p>
                <br />
                Agarradinhos às orelhas, os solitários e brincos curtos são ideais tanto para o dia como para a noite.<br />
                E melhor ainda ficam bem em qualquer formato de rosto.<br />
                Basta apenas escolher o modelo conforme a ocasião que você vai utilizar.

            </p>


            <br />

        </div>

        <div class="panel" title="Viajar" id="detailview2" data-footer="none">
            <p>
                <p style="text-align: center"> <b>Vai viajar?</b> </p>
                <br />
                Que bom, viajar é ótimo!<br />
                Traz um ar novo a tudo, muda o ambiente, permitindo um novo olhar sobre as coisas.<br />
                Para montar sua mala, em primeiro lugar, escolha as roupas que deseja levar.<br />
                Depois  escolha seus acessórios que possam fazer conjuntos entre si.<br />
                Não esqueça que um dia pode ter até três programas, um programa matinal, um à tarde e outro, geralmente mais sofisticado, à noite.  

            </p>

            <p>
                E o mais importante é como você vai transportar suas joias dentro da mala ou bolsa.<br />
                Pensando nisso a  &  lançou os <b>Cases Lux</b> para solucionar essa questão para voce.<br />
                Se vai ser uma viajem curta invista no <b>Case Mini Lux</b>, prefeito para ser colocado na bolsa e garantir a segurança das joias.<br />
                Mas, se sua viagem for durar uma semana ou mais aposte no Case Lux, tem compartimentos suficientes para várias opções.<br />


            </p>
                <img src="imagens/caselux.jpg" alt=" " style="max-width: 100%; border-image:round" />
                <img src="imagens/caselux2.jpg" alt=" " style="max-width: 100%; border-image:round" />
                <img src="imagens/caselux3.jpg" alt=" " style="max-width: 100%; border-image:round" />


        </div>


        <div class="panel" title="Agarre seu colar" id="colar" data-footer="none">
            <p>
           <p>
                Um, dois, três, quatro colares longos de pedras.<br />
                Isso mesmo você pode usá-los juntos para fazer parecer que é um só.<br />
                Monte o seu com todas as opções que você mais gosta!<br />

            </p>

                <img src="imagens/colar3.jpg" alt=" " style="max-width: 100%; border-image:round"  /> &nbsp;
                <img src="imagens/colar.jpg" alt=" " style="max-width: 100%; border-image:round"  />
                <img src="imagens/colar2.jpg" alt=" " style="max-width: 100%; border-image:round"  />

        </div>



    </div>

    <!--Footer with Tabs or Navigation bar -->
    <div id="navbar">
        <a href="#page1" id='tab1' class="icon home" data-transition="none">Home</a>
        <a href="#page2" id='tab2' class="icon heart" data-transition="none">Tendências</a>
        <a href="#page3" id='tab3' class="icon info" data-transition="none">Dicas</a>
   <!--     <a href="#page4" id='tab4' class="icon user" data-transition="none">Profile</a>-->
    </div>

</div>
</body>


    <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="appframework/af.ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="appframework/icons.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="appframework/appframework.ui.min.js"></script>



 <script type="text/javascript">
        function onDeviceReady() {
            $.ui.launch();
            intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
        }
        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ui.autoLaunch = false;
        $.ui.animateHeaders = false;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ui.launch();
        });
    </script>    


</html>
```

[image: Errado]

[image: Correto]

Comment: Poderia detalhar mais o seu problema? Mostrar algum código? Uma screenshot do erro?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Eu não consigo adicionar imagem aqui, mas vou postar o meu código para você ver. Basicamente é um app desenvolvido em HTML5 com o appframework da Intel, coisa simples, apenas para exibição de textos, nada demais, ao invés do menu convencional, ele tem um div que fica no rodapé da pagina onde contem este tal menu, com icones, bem legal...No emulador ele aparece normal, sem nenhuma alteração,com os menus numa boa, porém quando exporto o aplicativo e instalo ele direto no meu Smartphone, o menu não aparece.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar consegui adicionar as imagens

Comment: Tenta tirar um logcat do seu dispositivo rodando o aplicativo... Ajudaria bastante a identificar o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Todo o problema foi causado porque o SDK não carregava uma unica imagem e desencadeava uma série de erros ao longo do projeto.

Bastou retirar o link da imagem do projeto e tudo correu bem.

Graças a dica do @igor.araujo Eu analisei o LogCat e pude perceber o problema.